# TSQL: Trouble with creating function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create T-SQL function from Northwind to return new table, that will containt ProductID, ProductName, UnitsInStock and new column indicating if there are more UnitsInStock than function parameter.

**Example**: Let's have table of 2 products. First has 10 units in stock, second has 5. So function with parameter 6 should return:

1, Product1, 10, YES

2, Product2, 5, NO

Here's my non working code sofar :(

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ProductsReorder
    (
    @minValue int
    )
RETURNS  @tabvar TABLE (int _ProductID, nvarchar _ProductName, int _UnitsInStock, nvarchar _Reorder) 
AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tabvar 
           SELECT ProductID, ProductName, UnitsInStock, Reorder =
           CASE
            WHEN UnitsInStock > @minValue THEN "YES"
            ELSE "NO"
           END 
            FROM Products
        RETURN
    END
```

T-SQL gives me this not really helpful answer: "**Column, parameter, or variable#1: Cannot find data type _ProductID**". I googled but I found gazillion different issues for such a result.

I dunno if it's good to use CASE here, I have a little Oracle background and decode function was great for these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table definition, you should put the column name first, then the data type.  For example

```
_UnitsInStock int, ...
```

also, the NVARCHAR data type needs a length value.

```
_ProductName nvarchar(20)
```

Comment: Wow this was lame mistake! Thank you very much :) I'll accept answer asap.

Answer (score 3):

it's an easy answer -- especially as you are from oracle

the table definition in your function is the wrong way round.

Replace:

```
@tabvar TABLE (int _ProductID, nvarchar _ProductName, int _UnitsInStock, nvarchar _Reorder)
```

with something like

```
@tabvar TABLE ([_ProductID] INT, [_ProductName] NVARCHAR(50), [_UnitsInStrock] INT, [_Reorder] NVARCHAR(50))
```

In sql server the types come after the column names

Comment: Thanks pal, but bobs was little faster :))